# Subviews do not resize properly when animating constraints

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, autolayout, subview

I need to change size and position of a subview (call it playerView) of a view of a view controller. I have created properties for constraints I need to change. But when I animate the changes, only playerView is animated, but all of it's subviews are not: their size is changed instantly.

Here's the text:

```
self.playerViewTop.constant = screenHeight - MinizedPlayerTopOffset;
self.playerViewLeading.constant = MinimizedPlayerOffset;
self.playerViewWidth.constant = MinimizedPlayerWidth;
self.playerViewHeight.constant = MinimizedPlayerHeight;

[UIView animateWithDuration: 2.0 animations: ^
{
    [self.view layoutSubviews];
}];
```

I do not understand why that happens since I use autoLayout. Please help.

Comment: call `layoutIfNeeded` before setting the constraints and also in the animation closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `layoutIfNeeded()` in the animations block, *not* `layoutSubviews()`.

(You should actually never call `layoutSubviews()` yourself. It's a method called by the system during a layout pass and only intended for that purpose.)

Comment: Changing the method fixed the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
[self.subView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[self.subView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f delay:0.0f 
options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews animations:^{
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer].